# How to return the SUM value using a distinct value from referenced table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following structure in a schema:

```
 -------------------------------     ----------------------------                                        
 |           m_user            |     |          person          |       
 -------------------------------     ----------------------------                                   
 |  UUID  |  ID   |  PLATFORM  |     |  ID   |  NAME  |  EMAIL  |            
 | 456789 | 22222 |     TG     |     | 22222 | JOSEPH | J@CM.CO |          
 | 987654 | 22222 |     MS     |     | 85858 | MARKUS | M@GM.CO |          
 | 948576 | 85858 |     TG     |     | 36363 | ANDREA | A@GM.CO |              
 -------------------------------     ----------------------------                                        

 -------------------------------------------------
 |                    plan                       |
 -------------------------------------------------
 |     ID     |   HOURS  |    DATE    |  CLIENT  |
 |    22222   |    72    | 2017-12-05 | CLIENT11 |
 |    22222   |    88    | 2017-12-25 | CLIENT11 |
 |    85858   |    48    | 2017-12-05 | CLIENT12 |
 -------------------------------------------------
```

I need to return the `SUM` of `HOURS` planned for each user that exists in `m_user` table. `m_user` allow only one `ID` per platform: the same user can be on two platform, but own an unique ID that apply for both platforms.

The problem occur when the results show duplicate `SUM` values because the ID appear two times in `m_user` table. This is the query:

```
SELECT  ps.id
        ps.name,
        ps.email,
        SUM(pl.hours) AS hours
FROM  schema.person AS ps
JOIN  schema.m_user AS usr ON ps.id = usr.id
JOIN  schema.plan   AS pl  ON usr.id = pl.id      -- Here is the problem, I think
WHERE  pl.client = 'CLIENT11'     AND
       pl.date BETWEEN '2017-12-01' AND '2017-12-31'
GROUP BY id, name, email;
```

I've tried using `DISTINCT` and `DISTINCT ON (usr.id)` but the result given is the same.

Here is the result I get:

```
--------------------------------------
|   ID  |  NAME  |  EMAIL  |  HOURS  |
--------------------------------------
| 22222 | JOSEPH | J@CM.CO |   320   |     -- <- 320 instead of 160
|  ...  |  ....  |   ....  |   ...   |
--------------------------------------
```

I am new to SQL, so I think this is simple error that I am not able to figure right now, I also have tried to use `OVER (PARTITION BY usr.id)` AND `LIMIT 1` but again I get 320 for every row where `22222` appear. Do I need to use a CTE to perform this query? I hope you can help me, thank you (I am currently using PostgreSQL, but I think this problem apply for SQL in general so I set SQL tag).

Comment: Only tag with the products you are really using.

Comment: If the dates were 12/01 - 12/15, then what would the results be?  How do you decide which plan goes to which user?

Comment: Oh, thank you Gordon, I'll remember for the next time. The query must return the total hours planned in the given client (CLIENT11) in the current date range. In that case (12/01 - 12/15) only 72 hours but I think the query will return 144 instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always phrase this as:

```
SELECT ps.id, ps.name, ps.email, SUM(pl.hours) AS hours
FROM schema.person ps JOIN
     (SELECT usr.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id) as seqnum
      FROM schema.m_user usr 
     ) usr
     ON ps.id = usr.id JOIN 
     schema.plan pl
     ON usr.id = pl.id AND seqnum = 1
WHERE  pl.client = 'CLIENT11' AND
       pl.date BETWEEN '2017-12-01' AND '2017-12-31'
GROUP BY id, name, email;
```

This selects one row for the `join`.

Comment: I think that there is more a problem with his database design than with his query. Anyway, this is obviously correct.

Comment: What do you can recommend me @Matthias? What do you think is a bad design?

Comment: @M.Montoya For me, this looks like you are having a user with the id 22222 that uses two platforms. Since the plan basically refers to the person, you are billing him twice since you are creating a cartesian product of m_user and plan. If I understand the context right, I would suggest giving every row an independent id column and building relations with another column like this: `on m_user.id = plan.m_user_id`. In that way, the plan sticks to one single m_user.

Answer (score 1):

Removed the join on m_user.  Use subquery on m_user table to find the list of users.

```
SELECT  ps.id,
        ps.name,
        ps.email,
        SUM(pl.hours) AS hours
FROM   schema.person AS ps
JOIN   schema.plan   AS pl  ON ps.id = pl.id    
WHERE  pl.client = 'CLIENT11'     AND
       pl.date BETWEEN '2017-12-01' AND '2017-12-31'
AND    ps.id IN ( SELECT usr.id FROM  schema.m_user AS usr ) 
GROUP BY ps.id, ps.name, ps.email;
```

sqlfiddle: [sqlfiddle.com/#!17/5996e/1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/5996e/1)